# How do I get an Option<T> from an Entity Framework Core database call?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm struggling with [Language-Ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext), and can't seem to find a neat way to do this.

In non-functional code, I could do something like this...

```cs
async Task DoFerretStuff(string id) {
  Ferret? ferret = await ctx.Ferrets.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.id == id);
  if (ferret == null) {
    // Do whatever needs doing when we can't find the ferret
  } else {
    // Do ferret stuff
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do this in a more functional way, and assumed I would be able to do something like this...

```cs
async Task<Unit> DoFerretStuff(string id) =>
  new Option<Ferret>(await ctx.Ferrets.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == id))
    .Match(ferret => {
      // Do ferret stuff
      return unit;
    },
    () => {
      // Do whatever needs doing when we can't find the ferret
      return unit;
    });
```

However, this gives a compiler error on the first line...

> cannot convert from 'Ferret' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I don't understand why, as I thought the idea was that you could pass a (possibly null) object into the constructor for `Option<T>` and it would give either a `Some<T>` or a `None<T>`.

Please can someone explain how I should do this sort of thing in a functional way.

Thanks

Comment: What's the compiler error? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72338779/edit) the question by adding the actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Option` constructor [takes an `IEnumerable<A>` as argument](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Option/Option/index.html#Option_1_Option_0), which explains the compiler error.

Try [the static `Prelude.Optional` function](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Option/Option/index.html#Prelude_0_Optional_1) instead. One of those overloads takes a nullable value and converts it to `Option<A>`.

All that said, if you want to immediately `Match` on it afterwards to perform another side effect, then what are you gaining, compared to `if/else`?

FP would typically involve passing an immutable value (such as `Option<Ferret>`) to a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). The value can come from an impure action, such as `ctx.Ferrets.FirstOrDefaultAsync`, but it could also just be a value created on the spot. A pure function wouldn't care.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. Finding it hard to navigate this library, but enjoying the elegance it gives. As for your comment about `if/else`, you're right in the noddy example I showed. My real code is more complex and does pass around immutable values (or will when I've finished it). I was just trying to keep the sample code short so it was easy to see my question. Thanks very much